# My colours in submenus are messed up (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu

When mouse is over an option, its just fine. But otherwise its unreadable!
It was just fine before I turned my PC on this morning. If someone knows how to fix it please help.

Image here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dafbj.jpg